AudioKit: how to normalize an audiofile (AudioKit/Swift)
Previously the following code could normalize an audiofile. But in AudioKit 5, AKAudioFile() was removed and so for some reason normalize functionality also fell through the cracks. So, how do I normalize an audio file (.caf file) in xcode/swift? I need to make the audio file louder (or softer) based on the recorded volume.
Thank you so much
if let file = try? AKAudioFile(forReading: url) {
    if let normalizedFile = try? file.normalized(newMaxLevel: -4) {
        Swift.print("Normalized file sucess: \(normalizedFile.maxLevel)")
    }
}

